# Creating Multiple Levels AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

Hey Guys so I'm having a little trouble creating Multiple levels. I'm not so sure if im creating them the right way but i have a player and goal_1, goal_2, etc.. Basically when the player hitTestObject the goal_1 i want it to go to a new function called level_2 then level_3 after that hitTest. so Level_1 works just fine the hitTest works and it initializes level_2 but when i try to hitTest the player and goal_2 or even goal_1 again it just goes through it and doesnt do anything.

I understand now that level_2 isnt being called every frame like level_1 since its not part of the Enter_Frame listener. But i cant figure out how to have multiple Enter Frame events and not have them run simultaneously. If thats even the right way to create multiple levels.

Can you see what i could do in order to make it work?

```
private function gameLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        playerShoot();
        playerControl();
        playerStageBoundaries();

        checkEndGameCondition();
        checkPlayerOffScreen();

        level_1();
    }


    private function level_1():void 
    {


        if(player.hitTestObject(mGoal_1))
           {

            trace("Goal_1 Collision");
            //Remove button for constant movement
            btnShootPlayer = false;
            mGoal_1.destroyGoal_1();
            player.destroyPlayer();
            //Update High Score text
            nScore += 10;
            updateHighScore();
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            //Update level
            nLevel++;
            updatePlayerLevel();
            level_2();

           }else
           {

               checkEndGameCondition();
           }
    }



    public function level_2():void 
    {

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
       TweenMax.to(mGoal_1, 1, {y:40, repeat:-1, yoyo:true, ease:Power0.easeInOut});
        trace("Level_2 Initiated");
        //Keep Text Scores initiated
        updateHighScore();
        updatePlayerLives();

        player = new mPlayer();
        stage.addChild(player);
        player.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 280;
        player.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        mGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        stage.addChild(mGoal_1);
        mGoal_1.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 300;
        mGoal_1.y = (stage.stageHeight) - 35;

        if (player.hitTestObject(mGoal_1))
        {
            trace("Level 2 Hit test works!");


            nScore += 10;
            updateHighScore();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read too carefully all the code, but I guess you can use a function variable. Declare it on class level (outside any function):

```
var _doFunction:Function;
```

than, instead calling level1 function, pass the reference and call the _doFunction:

```
_doFunction = level1;
_doFunction();//or _doFunction.call(); - see Adobes documentation
```

when you are done with the level1, than pass the next level:

```
_doFunction = level2;
```

P.S. don't forget to accept the answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting. So declare the function as: Private function _doFunction:Function;           Then would i remove level_1 function from my gameLoop add the -doFunction inside my Enter_Frame gameLoop like this -doFucntion();   Ten proceed to call on them as you stated above?

Comment: I guess you dont do it as i stated above i got this error when trying to add the the function inside the Enter_Frame loop TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.

Comment: after you declare the variable function, don't forget to assign a function to it, e.g. level1. In the game loop you'll need to call only _doFucntion(). Then,when the condition is met in level1, reassign the _doFucntion to point level2 function.

Comment: Alright so i added the _doFunction(); inside the Gameloop and declared it in my constructor function as:  levelManager = level_1;  levelManager();    Then in my Level_1 Function i added this to the hitTest: levelManager = level_2;
    levelManager();     It works perfectly fine the trace is traced 25 frames per second. So thank you so much! The only problem is that nothing works in level_2 the objects are added but arnt interactive guess ill have to figure that out somehow but thanks so much man for taking the time to help!

Comment: Yeah im not sure if my player is moving 25 frames per sec. i traced it and it only moves once on level_2

Comment: you need to call levelManager() only in the game loop. don't call it inside the functions - you are calling itself. Remember, levelManager stores references, not the actual function, so if store level2 for example, and then you call it inside level2 - you have endless loop.

Comment: Ohhh Okay makes perfect sense! Thanks alot Rizzle for the explanation ill try that out today!

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe im adding my players to the stage the wrong way? Sorry for bugging but do you think adding them to the stage via eventListener Added_TO_Stage would do the trick? movieClips are not originally on the stage by the way. Whats happening is when i get to level_2 and move my player up or down its repeating itself like crazy instead of one player their are a lot of players when you move the up or down key. Seems like an endless loop? But i did what you said.